# How to trigger pipeline API in AzureDevOps from Python (urllib3)

Tags: python, azure-devops, urllib3

I have to trigger a pipeline in Azure DevOps from a python script. I have already found out that i need a private access token and that part is fine. I can, however, not get the script to work. I am trying something like this:

```
data = [
     {
     }
    ]
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('POST', api_url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json', "Authorization": private_access_token}, body=data)
    print(r.status)
    print(r.data)
```

Its a requirement that i have to use urllib3 because I cant use the requests package

data is empty, because looking at the parameters here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0. Then i dont need any input data? I just want to trigger a pipeline, nothing else

Error message is not very helpful. I get error message 203.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using:

```
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+private_access_token, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
    data = {}
    a = json.dumps(data)
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('POST', api_url, headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization}, body=a)
```