# How to run azure devops pipelines using RestAPi?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I tried using API endpoint of azure devops to run my pipeline. But when i checked on azure devops portal, the pipeline didn't started to run. I am sharing my code here.

```
personal_access_token='PAT',
organization_url='url'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+personal_access_token, 'ascii')), 'ascii')
headers={'Accept':'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization}
credentials=BasicAuthentication('',personal_access_token)
connect=Connection(base_url=organization_url,creds=credentials)
```

now I am looping the pipeline

response = requests.post(url_of_pipeline,headers=headers)

when i did request.post it should start to run the pipeline on azure devops, but when i checked on azure devops portal. The pipeline was not running. How this can be fixed?

Comment: What endpoint do you call?

Comment: I have used endpoint
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1
I am looking for how to run pipelines using python code.

Comment: Is using the CLI an option for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#az_pipelines_run

Comment: no I am looking for python code, till now i figured out that in request body i have to pass run parameters. How to pass that? I am getting these values when i did post request.

        {'$id': '1',
        'errorCode': 0,
        'eventId': 0,
        'innerException': None,
        'message': 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: runParameters',
        'typeKey': 'ArgumentNullException',
        'typeName': 'System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirement, you are using python to run the rest api to run the pipeline.

You can also try the following Python sample:

```
import requests
import json
import base64

pat = 'PAT'
authorization = str(base64.b64encode(bytes(':'+pat, 'ascii')), 'ascii')

print(authorization )

url = "https://dev.azure.com/{ORG}/{PROJECT}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineid}/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1"



payload = json.dumps({})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+authorization,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have an example how it can be done in powershell:

```
$AzureDevOpsPAT = "ocd2rrtds7bj6mff6jcxjllmaaXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$OrganizationName = "DEMOXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$ProjectName = "SOMEPROJECT"
$buildId = 177

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($AzureDevOpsPAT)")) }

$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/$($OrganizationName)/$($ProjectName)/_build?definitionId=$($buildId)" 

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method post -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader
```

However currently you have two endpoints vailable [Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) and [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)

Comment: Ok so i got the answer after going through blogs this is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68171363/how-to-trigger-pipeline-api-in-azuredevops-from-python-urllib3

so here we have to pass an empty dictionary to the http requests to api and instead of using the request we have to use urllib3 and post an http request with request body as empty. And it will trigger the pipeline which will start to run.